# Wt Dynamic Charts and Graphs

Tags: charts, wt

Using Wt, a C library for Web Development, I am trying to upload a .wav file and then print its values in a chart. Is there a way to do that dynamically, in other words to add points to a chart that is already created?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way to do that, I once wrote some code to monitor Memory usage and print that info in a chart, just like the Performance tab of the Windows Task Manager. I used a boost thread to continuously update it. Here is some code that might put you in the right direction with your chart problem.

You will need a WCartesianChart

```
Wt::Chart::WCartesianChart* _chart_memory_display;
```

Now, the initialization for charts is actually pretty tricky. I wrote a function to do it. **NOTE:** This uses a #define PERFORMANCE_HISTORY 100 this is the amount of data the chart stores, as far as I know there is no limit, I just wanted the last 100 points.

```
Wt::Chart::WCartesianChart* CreateCartesianChart(WContainerWidget* parent)
{
WStandardItemModel *model = new WStandardItemModel(PERFORMANCE_HISTORY, 2, parent);

//Create the scatter plot.
Wt::Chart::WCartesianChart* chart = new Wt::Chart::WCartesianChart(parent);
//Give the chart an empty model to fill with data
chart->setModel(model);
//Set which column holds X data
chart->setXSeriesColumn(0);

//Get the axes
Wt::Chart::WAxis& x_axis  = chart->axis(Wt::Chart::Axis::XAxis);
Wt::Chart::WAxis& y1_axis = chart->axis(Wt::Chart::Axis::Y1Axis);
Wt::Chart::WAxis& y2_axis = chart->axis(Wt::Chart::Axis::Y2Axis);

//Modify axes attributes
x_axis.setRange(0, PERFORMANCE_HISTORY);
x_axis.setGridLinesEnabled(true);
x_axis.setLabelInterval(PERFORMANCE_HISTORY / 10);

y1_axis.setRange(0, 100);
y1_axis.setGridLinesEnabled(true);
y1_axis.setLabelInterval(10);

y2_axis.setRange(0, 100);
y2_axis.setVisible(true);
y2_axis.setLabelInterval(10);

//Set chart type
chart->setType(Wt::Chart::ChartType::ScatterPlot);

// Typically, for mathematical functions, you want the axes to cross at the 0 mark:
chart->axis(Wt::Chart::Axis::XAxis).setLocation(Wt::Chart::AxisValue::ZeroValue);
chart->axis(Wt::Chart::Axis::Y1Axis).setLocation(Wt::Chart::AxisValue::ZeroValue);
chart->axis(Wt::Chart::Axis::Y2Axis).setLocation(Wt::Chart::AxisValue::ZeroValue);

// Add the lines
Wt::Chart::WDataSeries s(1, Wt::Chart::SeriesType::LineSeries);
chart->addSeries(s);

//Size the display size of the chart, has no effect on scale
chart->resize(300, 300);

return chart;
}
```

Basically, WT charts need a model, and a data series to be ready to receive data. I **highly recommend reading the documentation** on anything in that function you do not recognize, it took me sometime to put the pieces together. Also, check out the WT widget gallery, it has chart and code samples.

Now, for the actual updating, I wrote another function.

```
void UpdateChartDisplay(Wt::WAbstractItemModel* data_model, double data)
{
//Update the old data
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < PERFORMANCE_HISTORY; i++)
{
  //Move all data back one index
  data_model->setData(i, 0, i);
  data_model->setData(i, 1, data_model->data(i+1, 1));
}

//Get the last index of the data
int insertion_point = PERFORMANCE_HISTORY - 1;

//Insert new data at the last index
data_model->setData(insertion_point, 0, insertion_point);
data_model->setData(insertion_point, 1, data);
}
```

Now, the data_model is just the model of the chart that is being updated,

```
_chart_memory_display->model()
```

the double coming in, is the data itself that is being added to the chart. I have a boost thread calling this function every second passing in new data, it looks exactly like the task manager when running. I am not sure if you are trying to update it dynamically or just fill it with data, but I hope this helps and puts you on the right track!

Comment: Thanks much for this. I have been  struggling with the Wt examples, which are way too complicated - they should provide a very simple working example. The Wt docs that I have found are very dense and don't seem to explain how to do something simply, step by step. If you know some docs that do, please let me know. I love Wt and had very little problem getting up to speed with it, having experience with many other GUI frameworks. But the charting stuff is nasty.

Comment: The only solid documentation I found is their standard documents here http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/index.html and the widget gallery. They also have an official forum http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/projects/wt/boards where you can post questions to the community or the devs. You can also request features from the devs, I actually got one approved not too long ago :D Feature #3175 http://redmine.webtoolkit.eu/issues/3175#change-9919
Other than that, I just Google or dig through Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've seen most of that stuff - thanks. _Other than that, I just Google or dig through Stack Overflow_ : Mostly I just keep hacking until I get something to work. Having worked a lot with Qt and gtkmm, I find Wt to be quite elegant and intuitive most of the time - I got up and running very fast with it. But the charting is nasty - not that it's much better in other frameworks - good charts are inherently complex, especially if you're doing real time updating with them. What's sorely lacking is a good book on Wt that organizes things and walks you through. I love Wt - very powerful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you have a model and you update that model, the graph automatically updated as a view.

Create your own model and do your business logic there. Let Wt handle the graph view.